# Change horizontal scrolling to vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I change from horizontal scrolling to vertical scrolling? I tried to remove `display: flex` but once I remove, the image will not fill up the entire web page.

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  img {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514117445516-2ecfc9c4ec90?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=0e0b58fcf67fa6e8a010322d617e39af' alt='Mountain massif, sunbathed, partly covered in show.'
  />
  <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510325805092-2951ab330b7d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=017cf46443f4821a375c20e8c68e37f0' alt='Tiny bird with pale brown, orange and white feathers in an evergreen tree.'
  />
  <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514848567240-a81cb051807a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=3a0e476ab712db0eb68ab121a21c54de' alt='Close-up of yellow rose opening up.' />
  <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465408522361-a6f502298219?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=7a6bd1244c42d1dbd3984a4c13981666' alt='Fast and foamy creek in the middle of the forest.'
  />
  <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503843778847-2b8bdce2ed3d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&amp;s=d547781176ce182eeeb7303bac05abf4' alt='Fluffy little tabby with blue eyes climbing up a tree.'
  />
</div>
```

Comment: @ChayimFriedman those are actually publicly available image from unsplash and they display for me. Nevertheless I think this question could be improved by considering https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and researching the problem at hand a bit more. A good ressource might be [this CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/)

Comment: add `flex-wrap:wrap` and remove `overflow-y:hidden` to start with. Also check the typo *(align-items and overflow are not seperated )*